# Regex keep greedy even when using lazy quantifier

Tags: javascript, regex

Here is my regex `^((\{.+:.+\})|([^{:}]))+?$`.

Here is what i want:
Valid case: `{test:test1} {test2:test3} test4 test5`.
Invalid case: `{test:}`, `{test1: test2`, `test1: test3}`.

It's mean whenever my string have one of this three character: `'{' ':', '}'` it must also have 2 remaning character.

My regex is working well when my string not end with `}` character. I guess it's because of greedy quantifier. But i already put `?` character after `+` quantifier it's still not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `[^}]+` instead `.+` inside `(\{.+:.+\})`

Comment: Try `^(?:\{[^{}:]*:[^:{}]*}|[^{:}])+$`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/RrtZh3/1)

Comment: Wow its working, thank you all!, but i dont understand so much, can u guys explain for me? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?:\{[^{}:]*:[^:{}]*}|[^{:}])+$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RrtZh3/1).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:\{[^{}:]*:[^:{}]*}|[^{:}])+` - a [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do) matching 1 or more occurrences of

  - `\{[^{}:]*:[^:{}]*}` - a `{`, then any 0+ chars other than `{`, `}` and `:`, then `:`, then any 0+ chars other than `{`, `}` and `:`, and a `}`
  - `|` - or
  - `[^{:}]` - any char but `{`, `}` and `:`
- `$` - end of string.